# Blazor не показывает загруженную картинки из https://localhost:7270/ (из папки ....\bin\Debug\net7.0\wwwroot\)

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

Запускаю проект Blazor локально, для отладки (https://localhost:7270/)

Из компонента картинку загружаю в папку
G:\6Blazor\KKShop\KKShopRadzenNew\bin\Debug\net7.0\wwwroot\pictures\countries

Картинка правильно загружается, она там появляется 4.jpg

Потом открываю станицу/компонент и там есть ссылка на загруженную картинку:

```
<img src="pictures\countries\4.jpg">
```

НО! картинку не видно, выводится только значок.

Но когда размещаю проект на хостинге всё прекрасно работает.

Почему при запуске на https://localhost:7270/
не подгружается картинка из
....\bin\Debug\net7.0\wwwroot\pictures\countries ???

Что сделать, чтобы картинку было видно при отладке?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Blazor` предлагает [динамическое использование](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/blazor/images?view=aspnetcore-8.0) , классно✅. Попробуйте.

В вашем конкретном случае я вижу <strike>две</strike> ошибки:

1. папка `wwwroot` должна быть в корне решения, а не в папке `debug` (в папке debug она появляется после публикации, если к примеру вы публиковали ваше приложение в режиме debug, но для использования путей **в режиме отладки Blazor базируется по папке в корне проекта**, и именно поэтому у вас работает при публикации, потому как он берет из папки, что вы указали, и там есть это фото...Но корректней, делать немного по другому, но это вопрос про публикацию и выставления путей.)
2. <strike>слеш на путь обратный</strike> `<img src="pictures/countries/4.jpg">` если бы вы были на Windows, а это возможно linux ...если вы говорите, что при публикации работает, значит слеш верный...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]